# KQL extend column with a static link

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a query that I am parsing using an automation runbook. When I extend a column that has a static URL reference, I get the error:

`BadArgumentError- Query could not be parsed at 'https'`

The extend looks like this:

`| extend Body = strcat(@"<p>The following items are expiring <strong>within 30 days</strong></p>", "<p>Plan to remediate as soon as possible.</p>", "<p>If the item is no longer valid, please remove it from ", "<a href="https://portal.azure.com/#@fabrikam.com/resource/subscriptions/0000-0000-000/resourceGroups/000resourcegroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/Fabrikam_Monitoring/availability">Application Insights</a></p>", "<p>Property: ", Name, "</p>", "<p>Expires In: ", ExpiresIn, " day(s) " "</p>")`

The runbook posts to a logic app via a webhook which sends a readable output to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [triple backtick (```)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string#multi-line-string-literals) to qualify strings that contain single and/or double quotes.

P.S.
Also note the following:

> [Splicing string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string#splicing-string-literals)
> Two or more string literals are automatically joined to form a new string literal in the query if they have nothing between them, or they're separated only by whitespace and comments.

````
print Name = "MyName", ExpiresIn = "7"
| extend Body = 
    strcat
    (
        "<p>The following items are expiring <strong>within 30 days</strong></p>"
        "<p>Plan to remediate as soon as possible.</p>"
        "<p>If the item is no longer valid, please remove it from "
        ```<a href="https://portal.azure.com/#@fabrikam.com/resource/subscriptions/0000-0000-000/resourceGroups/000resourcegroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/Fabrikam_Monitoring/availability">Application Insights</a></p>```
        "<p>Property: "
        , Name
        , "</p>" 
          "<p>Expires In: " 
        ,ExpiresIn 
        ," day(s) "
         "</p>"
    )
````

| Name | ExpiresIn | Body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MyName | 7 | The following items are expiring **within 30 days** Plan to remediate as soon as possible. If the item is no longer valid, please remove it from [Application Insights](https://portal.azure.com/#@fabrikam.com/resource/subscriptions/0000-0000-000/resourceGroups/000resourcegroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/Fabrikam_Monitoring/availability) Property: MyName Expires In: 7 day(s) |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21SwW7bMAy9F%20g/EN6lBdKowA4DCjfoBmxDDh122H1RbDomJosCyaT1sI%20f5LirN4wHi3oS36OfmISiwRc/INxD9TiWrFrBx%20dEgrqNBX1XXV78Anw2jC184HbM4OUF5FCTxts5vzovJao6bb71CB2HwE8UD0CGg4IXzDSZuUB1LuZ42DyR9RTh7S20ftTazXDt0qb6m/Jr8BGMQXDAlrwheAVljmVNrEr7gOv/FG47sNxOaQJIITKELIECJx%20oXUEK6BULL5/KNeiEB1iQ7Ha72kMv2N1XvVnSO%20cSi/mw9j%20PguuGB/fmofN7oR9%20mLbZPj5Kg06Pe22EkhFHdbc5bl4%20fy59Fj6m6fAFORTEJeETtSjqBmqElTtbU1Q69KYuqySOGHP6aVb%20/siRjIvBzp88Bb%20nQDZWm/cpBcqPlZuA7cxQOz/5nH/vH6eFE4qNd0sTVtOYLPfV5DW8QufqeXiyTK5fnK5ep2oBVuXdr/R6KTUzn4Hr3%20RDo4KkAgAA)